# Applying categorized symbololgy to many layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have many layers that I want to symbol with same rules

Currently, I right click on each layer-->properties-->style-->
categorized-->column-->use(my case)-->classify-->
-switchboard - star symbol
-other - regular circle symbol

now this rules apply to all of the layers that I have.
switchboards get a star and other points get a circles.

it's just that I have many layers that I need to apply it to.

Is there a way to do it faster?

For each layer I use an individual color, but I use the same color for the star and the circle
e.g
if in switchboard 3 I have 24 regular points and 1 switchboard point
for the regular I use blue circle and for the switchboard I use blue star
I do that by changing the color of each symbol
and that's only for switchboard 3. for switchboard 4 I'll use the color red

Answer (score 7):

You can copy and paste styles between layers.

So apply as you do for the first layer.

Then right click on the layer in the layers panel, choose **Styles> Copy Style**.

Then for the other layers, right click, choose **Styles> Paste Style**.

Comment: Alternatively, you can save **styling** through `Layer Properties > Style > Style (bottom) > Save Style` and then apply them to other layers.

Comment: Okay, So now I have many layers having the style that I need but in the same color, any Idea how I apply different colors on the layers?

Comment: I recommend you set-up a keyboard shortcut for copying and pasting styles, as this is a common thing to do. (I personally have it set-up as Shift+C and Shift+V)

Answer (score 4):

You can set one general rule-based symbology that will apply to all your layers. Just build new rules with your desired symbologies (color for each layer, symbol for each feature type) using those references:

```
"your_field" = value AND @layer_id = 'layer_id'
```

In the expression string builder, you can find the layer ID values in the ***Map Layers*** section while the `@layer_id` variable is found in the ***Variables*** section. `"your_field"` should be the condition field for point symbology and the `'layer_id'` value will control which layer the rule will apply to.

From there, when the rule-based symbology is built, just use the copy/paste style options from the right-click contextual menu in the layers panel.

Here's an example:
[image]